# STM32 Cmake STM32Workbench project

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, arm, stm32

I am trying to write a CMakeLists.txt file for my STM32 project. I am using cmake files from this repo: https://github.com/ObKo/stm32-cmake. Building from command line works fine. I am doing it in that way:

```
cmake -C "..\STM32F207ZCTx_config.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ..
make.exe -j4
```

In cache file I have some variables set:

```
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "D:/STM32Workbench/plugins/fr.ac6.mcu.externaltools.arm-none.win32_1.16.0.201807130628/tools/make/make.exe"  CACHE STRING "stm32 make")
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "stm32-cmake/gcc_stm32.cmake" CACHE STRING "stm32 toolchain")
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX "D:/STM32Workbench/plugins/fr.ac6.mcu.externaltools.arm-none.win32_1.16.0.201807130628/tools/compiler" CACHE STRING "arm toolchain path")
```

When I import created project to STM32 Workbench it generates a lot of errors "unresolved external" regarding stdint.h types (e.g. uint8_t, int32_t).

After some debugging this problem I realized that there are missing some defines which are used by stdint.h header. I checked out the compiler with this command:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -dM -E out.h
```

And got the list of defines in arm-none-eabi-gcc:

```
#define __UINTMAX_TYPE__ long long unsigned int
#define __INT_FAST16_TYPE__ int
#define __INT_FAST64_TYPE__ long long int
#define __INT_FAST32_TYPE__ int
#define __UINT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __INT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short int
... and much more
```

These defines are needed by stdint.h to create correct uint8_t and other types.

I can add manually these defines to Eclipse project, but I am wondering if there is method to add these defines to Eclipse project automagically from CMake?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: IMHO not cmake is responsible for defining those types, but your {g,new}libc. Do you use an reasonably current version?

Comment: Problem was in STM32Workbench. Sources was excluded from build and from indexer. Right mouse click on source, Properties, C/C++ General, Preprocessor Include Paths, Exclude resource from build.

Comment: Make that an answer and mark it then as a solution ;) Take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are not familiar with how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in STM32Workbench. Sources were excluded from build and from indexer.

To fix it - right mouse click on source, Properties, C/C++ General, Preprocessor Include Paths, uncheck **Exclude resource from build**.
Now the indexer is able to find all sources and all "unresolved external" errors are gone!